# How change border color on round button (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

i have four button.

And two button have round corner **(1-(top Left, bottom Left),4-(top Right, bottom Right))**.

How can i change border color how on image.

```
// Right Button
let T1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:Delete.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15, height:  15))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = T1.cgPath
    Delete.layer.mask = maskLayer
// Left Button
let T2 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:Copy.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topLeft, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 15, height:  15))
    let maskLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer2.path = T2.cgPath
    Copy.layer.mask = maskLayer2
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a 'color' property on 'maskLayer'?

Comment: You have 4 buttons inside of a cointainer view? then you can setup border color with `containerView.layer.borderWidth = 1` and  `containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor`

Comment: @ReinierMelian Inside UIView

Comment: then add you `UIView` as `IBOutlet` and setup the `layer.borderWidth` and `layer.borderColor` as I told you in my previous comment

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you so much)

Comment: @B2Fq added as an answer

Comment: @B2Fq, you can check this answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319087/16403924

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your `UIView` "containerView" as `IBOutlet` and setup your `containerView.layer.borderWidth = yourDesiredWidth` and setup the `containerView.layer.borderColor = yourNeededColor.cgColor`

Answer (score 2):

`UIButton.layer.cornerRadius`, `UIButton.layer.borderColor`, and `UIButton.layer.borderWidth`. `layer` is a property of `UIView`, so you can pretty much customize any view with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.layer.borderColor = CGColor(srgbRed: 255/255, green: 126/255, blue: 121/255, alpha: 1)
```